# Swift String to bytes in a buffer

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

I have a swift String that only contains ASCII characters. I have to put them in a char* buffer that I then cast to void* and to do this process in reverse to get the replied string.

Example:

```
bool query(const void* queryString, byte queryLength, void* replyBuffer, byte bufferLength);
```

So, I have to setup two buffers. One that will hold my query string and one, that is 180 bytes large, to contain the reply.

How can I setup those two buffers and copy back and forth the strings ? I tried exploring `_bridgeToObjectiveC().utf8String` ans well as unsafemutablepointer... but I feel lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can set up the buffers and pass them to the C function:

```
let queryString = "Query ..."

let queryBuffer = Array(queryString.utf8)
var replyBuffer = Array(repeating: UInt8(0), count: 180)

let result = query(queryBuffer, numericCast(queryBuffer.count), &replyBuffer, numericCast(replyBuffer.count))
```

`queryBuffer` is an array with the UTF-8 representation of the string,
and `replyBuffer` an array containing a specified amount of zero bytes.

The arrays are passed to the function with `queryBuffer` and `&replyBuffer`, respectively, which passes pointers to the element storage
to the C function.

If the result buffer is filled with a null-terminated C string on return
then you can create a Swift string with

```
let resultString = String(cString: replyBuffer)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What is the difference between `&Array(repeating: UInt8(0), count: 180)` and `let receiveBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 256)
  receiveBuffer.initialize(repeating: 0, count: 256)` ?

Comment: `Array(...)` creates local array variable, which is automatically disposed of when the current scope is left. You can use `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(...)` as well, that allocates memory, so you have to remember to release it eventually, otherwise you have a memory leak.